Is it possible to evaluate causal algorithms on real world observational data?
Lot of times I get asked to use causal algorithms (e.g. algorithms estimating intervention results, or in general causal inference algorithms) and to compare them against non-causal prediction algorithms on real-world observational data, without any additional knowledge. Is it possible to evaluate quantitatively (e.g. evaluating the $R^2$ of the fitting) causal algorithms on real data? Does the comparison causal vs non-causal algorithms make sense? Can you also provide or point me to an example (can also be synthetic, possibly with continuous data) supporting your answer?

SPOILER: here follow my thoughts as correct answer, but still I'd like to have confirmation or a proof I'm wrong.
My thoughts on this are the following: I think this is not possible as we either need the knowledge of the causal DAG or we need to have interventional data, not observational one. So I think the only way to evaluate causal algorithms against non-causal ones is on synthetic data, and once the synthetic example is shown to work in the causal model and not in the non-causal one. Then, the only thing to do is to use the correct algorithm for the task at hand: causal algorithms for "what-if" or interventional scenarios, non-causal ones for simple prediction ones. I also think that a non-causal model most of the times will over perform a causal one if evaluated on non-causal measures, such as the $R^2$ evaluating the fit of some predictions, given that they are designed and optimized exactly for that.

The classic reference comparing observational CI and experiments is

LaLonde, Robert J. “Evaluating the Econometric Evaluations of
Training Programs with Experimental Data.” The American Economic
Review 76, no. 4 (1986): 604–20.

A more recent example, combining many experiments with extremely rich data that would be inaccessible to the typical analyst and modern CI approaches, is

Gordon, Brett, Robert Moakler, and Florian Zettelmeyer. 2023. Close
Enough? A Large-Scale Exploration of Non-experimental Approaches to
Advertising Measurement. Marketing Science.(4): 768-793. (arxiv
preprint)

This paper also includes citations to the literature "bookended" by the two papers.
Another favorite cautionary tale about off-the-shelf ML tools and experiments is

Eva Ascarza, Raghuram Iyengar and Martin Schleicher, The perils of
proactive churn prevention using plan recommendations: Evidence from a
field experiment, Journal of Marketing Research (2016) 53(1),
46-60

A second approach is to see how sensitive your estimates are to assumptions about unobservables. An important paper in this literature

Oster, Emily. "Unobservable Selection and Coefficient Stability:
Theory and Evidence." Journal of Business & Economic Statistics,
vol. 37, no. 2, 2017, pp. 187-204.

This does not require having access to an experiment. You can see this approach in action in our paper on eBay sniping:

Matthew Backus, Thomas Blake, Dimitriy Masterov, Steven Tadelis,
Expectation, Disappointment, and Exit: Evidence on Reference Point
Formation from an Online Marketplace, Journal of the European Economic
Association, Volume 20, Issue 1, February 2022, Pages 116–149,
https://doi.org/10.1093/jeea/jvab033

A third approach is to simulate data from a behavioral model where you know the ground truth and show that your approach recovers the true parameters. I would put passing this test lower on the hierarchy of evidence compared to the experimental benchmark gold standard and Oster-like approaches. A more convincing version is to have this done by two separate people so that the DGPs are opaque to the evaluator.

+1 Just for Ascarza et al. really, that paper is bank.

@usεr11852 Brett Gordon did a very good podcast interviewing Eva Ascarza on the origins and results of that paper here.

Thank you for sharing that.

Thanks a lot @dimitriy for your answer, I'm slowly skimming the suggested papers. Are you also aware of any paper in which there is a comparison of statistical and causal data analysis approaches (e.g. regression vs double machine learning) on the same dataset?

@DaSim I can't think of any (though you can do DML with ordinary regression). I imagine that is because regression is guaranteed to be biased in these settings, so its use is precluded from the start.

It depends on your objective function and data
Some of the most basic motivations behind learning causal structure are to find variables to intervene on or to find sets of stable predictors that work equally well across environments.
If your objective is to do one of these things (or possibly something else causal structures are particularly well suited to), then it might make sense to think about them in the first place.
In order to evaluate them, you will need to have some kind of ground-truth knowledge, for example interventional data, a model of the data-generating process, etc..
Causal models are models in the true sense of the word - they don not simply fit a curve but aim to describe the data generating process. If you are interested purely in predictive quantities like R² (or MSE, accuracy, ...), what would be the point in doing any modeling? The best anyone could do is take all the data and fit some flexible regressor in a vanilla supervised learning style.
From your description it sounds like you are being approached by people with a mindset of "can only be better if it's causal, right?". That's not the way it works, and perhaps one way forward is to ask what exactly your predictor is supposed to do by being causal.
In summary: I'd say you're broadly right.
While there may be a bit of nuance regarding prediction under interventional shifts and it is theoretically possible to learn causal structure from observational data under extremely strong assumptions, I'd say your thoughts on the roles of causal and purely predictive algorithms are pretty spot-on.

My question was just focused on causal inference, but I think your reply still applies. Thanks for your point, I'd like to read other answers if possible before closing the question

@DaSim As an aside, you won't be able to close the question (that is to say people will still be able to answer it at any time in the future, even after you possibly accepted an answer). Questions can only be closed by moderators or by the community, and it happens only when a question is deemed problematic (e.g. because it's the duplicate of another one, or because it lacks enough information to give an answer, or because the question is not related to statistics, etc.).
